# Choropleth Map, Bokeh - Assigning patch colours based on property values

Tags: geojson, bokeh, choropleth

This is my first time trying to build a world map and using GeoJSONDataSource.
I'm trying to assign different colours to the patches, based on the country's 'continent' value in its properties.

Is it possible to do something along the following lines:

```
p.patches(... fill_color= colours['continent'])
```

Where colours is a dictionary with continent names as keys, and 'continent' is the country's continent value in the JSON data.

This is my current code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
import numpy as np
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource

with open('data.geojson') as c:
        countries = (c.read())

geo_source = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=countries)    
colours = {'Europe': 'red', 'Oceania': 'purple', 'Asia': 'blue', 'Africa': 'pink', "South America": 'green', "Antarctica": 'yellow', 'North America': 'orange', "Seven seas (open ocean)": 'red'}

p = figure(height=450, width=900, lod_threshold=1)
p.patches(xs='xs', ys='ys', fill_color='blue', source=geo_source)
p.multi_line(xs='xs', ys='ys', line_color='white', line_width=0.1, source=geo_source)

show(p)
```

**EDIT**

I have tried approaching this slightly differently by setting the fill_color attribute in patches to an array of colours like so:

```
a =[colours[c['properties']['continent']] for c in json.loads(countries)['features']]
```

When running this code in Jupyter Notebook, the following error comes up:

> Javascript error adding output! Error: attempted to retrieve property
>   array for nonexistent field 'fill_color' See your browser Javascript
>   console for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I did this function in order to asign to a geoJSON the data provided in another JSON.

My geoJSON has the international code for states (ISO 3166-2); my data joins on it.

```
for state in geo['features']:
    codState = str(state['properties']['ISO_3166-2'])

    if codState in data.keys():
        if data.values() != 0:
            state['properties']['data'] = data[codState]
dataJson = json.dumps(geo,ensure_ascii=True)
return dataJson
```